Supertuxkart is not running
I installed Supertuxkart but it won't run.
hasan@ubuntu:~$ supertuxkart 
supertuxkart: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libshaderc.so.1: undefined symbol: _ZTVN8spvtools5utils5TimerE


confirmed. use the flatpak version.

It looks like you're experiencing this bug:
https://groups.google.com/g/linux.debian.bugs.dist/c/F1cmusZVNBE?pli=1
Which is a bug in the dev version of libshaderc in Debian (presumably Ubuntu too) so it could potentially affect other things linked with that library.
That said, I prefer to play the version of supertuxkart from flathub, which is newer (and fixes some graphical issues for me as well).  I'd recommend that, perhaps as an alternative solution to your problem.
